# Control 4 M2Crypto

Tags: m2crypto

I put the M2Crypto file downloaded under the directory of dp3(shown in the figure). It worked before but doesn't now LMAO. Would like to know how that was[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzthJ.png).

I am running the files on Win 11 platform. When I tried to install the M2Crypto, always failures.
I don't know why it keeps talking about wheel tools can't be used to build.
Now I am considering Run it on Linux.
Would like to know why put the M2Crypto file in the directory of execute file, it worked before but doesn't now.
Or is there any command that can replace it.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Good day guys!

Comment: Ehm, what is `the M2Crypto file`? Could you at least give me the filename and where you get it from (URL)? If there are failure, could you copy here exactly whole process (what you did and what happened including all error messages verbatim), please?